# I need to have node.js ran on all my web pages

Tags: node.js, nginx

So I have created a node server to run a website and am running into an issue with how to have it run node on the rest of the site. currently it just runs on the login page. After logging in it goes to my homepage (homepage.html). The homepage is running off nginx. How can I have everything running off node?

here is my js file (auth.js)

```
const mysql=require("mysql");
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');

const db = mysql.createConnection({
    host: process.env.DATABASE_HOST,
    user: process.env.DATABASE_USER,
    password:process.env.DATABASE_PASSWORD,
    database:process.env.DATABASE
});

exports.login = async (req, res) => {
    try {

        const{email, password} = req.body;
        if(!email || !password){
            return res.status(400).render('login', {
                message:'Please provide an email and password'
            })
        }

       db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?', [email], async(error, results) =>{
           console.log(results);
           if(!results || !(await bcrypt.compare(password, results[0].password) ) ) {
               res.status(401).render('login', {
                   message: 'Email or Password is incorrect'
               })
           } else{
               const id = results[0].id;
               const token=jwt.sign({id:id}, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
                   expiresIn: process.env.JWT_EXPIRES_IN
               });
               console.log("The token is: "+token);

               const cookieOptions= {
                   expires: new Date(
                       Date.now + process.env.JWT_COOKIE_EXPIRES * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
                   ),
                   httpOnly: true
               }
               res.cookie('jwt', token, cookieOptions);
               res.status(200).redirect("http://zrgarri.it.pointpark.edu/CMPS480/homepage.html");
           }
       })

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

}

exports.register = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);

    const name = req.body.name;
    const email = req.body.email;
    const password = req.body.password;
    const passwordConfirm = req.body.passwordConfirm;

    db.query('SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=?', [email], async (error, results) => {
        if(error){
            console.log(error);
        }

        if(results.length > 0) {
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'Email already in use.'
            })
        } else if(password !== passwordConfirm){
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'Passwords do not match.'
          });
         }
    let hashedPassword= await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
    console.log(hashedPassword);

    db.query('INSERT INTO users SET ? ', {name: name, email: email, password: hashedPassword}, (error, results)=> {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            console.log(results);
            return res.render('register', {
                message: 'User Registered Successfully'
          });
     }
    });

 });

}
© 2020 GitHub, Inc.
```

Comment: Consider changing the title and rephrasing your question. Node cannot run on a webpage.

Comment: It looks like you are explicitly redirecting to an HTML page: `res.status(200).redirect("http://zrgarri.it.pointpark.edu/CMPS480/homepage.html");`. If you don't want to do that, don't do that. You might want to consider using a web framework.